# ADTs in F# and Scala

Tags: scala, f#, comparison, algebraic-data-types

What are the key differences between ADTs in F# and Scala? Is there anything that F#'s ADTs can do but Scala's ADTs cannot (and vice versa)?

Comment: I believe Scala supports co- and contravariance but F# does not (yet).

Answer (score 15):

Conceptually, I think that both languages provide the same power - in F# you can declare ADTs using *discriminated unions* and in Scala, you can use *case classes*. The declaration in Scala using classes may get a little bit longer than the F# version (as pointed out by Yin Zhu), but then you can use pattern matching with similar elegancy in both of the languages.

Here is an example ([from this article](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=166742)) of simplifying terms:

```
def simplify(term: Term) = term match {
  case Mul(Num(0), x) => Num(0)
  case Mul(Num(1), x) => x
  case _ => term
}
```

The same code in F# using `match` would look very similar:

```
let simplify term = 
  match term with 
  | Mul(Num(0), x) -> Num(0)
  | Mul(Num(1), x) -> x
  | _ -> term
```

**Differences** I think there are a few differences when it comes to more advanced (related) features.

- In Scala, each case is also a type, so you can for example define a method that takes `Num` or `Mul` as an argument. In F#, this is not possible, because `Num` and `Mul` are just constructors of type `Term`. I suppose this may be sometimes useful, but most of the time, you'll work with values of type `Term` anyway.
- Related to the previous point - in Scala, you can also define methods for individual cases. You can for example define a method in the `Num` class. In F#, all members have to be members of the `Term` type.
- In F#, you can use *active patterns* to hide the internal representation of the type (e.g. when exporting it from a module). This is very useful for library design. For example, you can define active patterns:

  ```
  val (|Mul|_|) // return Some(..) if Term represents multiplication
  val (|Num|_|) // return Some(..) if Term represents number
  ```

  The internal representation can change over time without affecting the library interface, so you can for example implement the interface like this:

  ```
  type Term = Binary of string * Term * Term | Num of int
  let (|Num|_|) = function Num n -> Some n | _ -> None 
  let (|Mul|_|) = function Binary("*", a, b) -> Some(a, b) | _ -> None
  ```

Comment: What is the difference between F# active patterns and scala extractors?

Answer (score -2):

First, there is nothing a language can, the other cannot.

What differs is the style.

I read a little bit Scala, but cannot write. I think binary search tree is a good example to compare the ADT style.

This is the code from http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/:

```
package binarytree {

  sealed abstract class Tree[+T]

  case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {
    override def toString = "T(" + value.toString + " " + left.toString + " " + right.toString + ")"
  }

  case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
    override def toString = "."
  }

  object Node {
    def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = Node(value, End, End)
  }
}
```

We can see that the style is quite OO.

Following is the main part of my code for Treap ( a balanced binary search tree ):

```
module Treap = 

    type node<'T> = {left: treap<'T>; right: treap<'T>; value: 'T; priority:int}
    and treap<'T>  = Empty | Node of node<'T>

    let rec lookup (k:'a) (t:'a treap) =
        match t with
            | Empty -> None
            | Node(n) -> 
                if k = n.value then Some(k)
                elif k < n.value then lookup k (n.left)
                else lookup k (n.right)

    let add (k:'a) (p:int) (tree:'a treap) = 
        let rotate xv xp yv yp a b c =
            if xp < yp then
                {value=xv; priority=xp; left=a; right=Node({value=yv;priority=yp;left=b;right=c})}
            else
                {value=yv; priority=yp; right=c; left=Node({value=xv; priority=xp; left=a; right=b})}

        let rec addNode (k:'a) (p:int) (tree:'a treap) = 
            match tree with
            | Empty -> {value=k; priority=p; left=Empty; right=Empty}, false
            | Node(n) ->
                if k=n.value then
                    n, true
                elif k<n.value then
                    let {value=xv; priority=xp; left=a; right=b}, dup = addNode k p (n.left) 
                    (rotate xv xp (n.value) (n.priority) a b (n.right)), dup
                else
                    let {value=yv; priority=yp; left=b; right=c}, dup = addNode k p (n.right)
                    (rotate (n.value) (n.priority) yv yp (n.left) b c), dup

        let n, dup = addNode k p tree
        Node(n)
```

I think Scala can also write in this style. However, Scala is more OO.