# How are F#'s Discriminated Unions different from Scala's Case Classes? or are they the same?

Tags: scala, f#, case-class, discriminated-union

I've looked around on the web to find something in scala that could resemble or work like the F# discriminated union but no matter where I look I can't really find anything, except for the case class that seems to resemble it slightly... but how exactly do they differ?

for example:

```ml
type Shape =
    | Circle of double
    | Square of double

let area =
    function
    | Circle radius -> 3.1415 * radius * radius
    | Square length -> length * length

let circle = Circle(15.0)
printfn "The circle's area is %A" (area circle)
```

is the above code basically a case class or would I have to do something different to gain the same functionality?

Comment: See also: [ADTs in F# and Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894799/adts-in-f-and-scala)

Comment: Looks like method overload in C or C++ or Java or Scala